# Execute commands on new terminal on cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am trying to execute a script on cygwin terminal.I want to start a new terminal, close the existing one and run the rest of commands present in the script on new terminal.

I have included the command :

```
            cygstart /bin/bash -li
```

at the end of my file to open a new terminal of cygwin.

But the rest of commands included after :

```
             cygstart /bin/bash -li
```

are being executed at the previous cygwin prompt only, not the new one.Even i could not figure out how to close the previous terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Cygstart just executes specified program in the new terminal window. Your script just opens new bash shell with cygstart and continues to work. I think you probably must to divide the script by two parts and call second of them via cygstart if it is really necessary. (Although as far as I know, there is a problem with passing of additional arguments to cygstart command.)